# What to use to fill a small HOLE in my concrete patio

Tags: concrete, hole

I have a 4" x 4" x 6" deep hole where a post had been on my cement patio.  The post rotted out and now I want to fill the hole and then place a post holder in that same spot.  What do you recommend to use to fill the hole?

Comment: How about concrete?

Comment: Not really helpful.  I found this.  Much more helpful --> https://www.lowes.com/pd/QUIKRETE-20-lbs-Anchoring-Cement/1116747

Answer (score 1):

I would get a holder designed to be held in with concrete, fill the hole and put the holder in this will secure the holder and hide the hole.